# How to contact authors of package quantregForest to correct function varImpPlot.qrf()

Tags: r, function

I am using the latest version (19-Dec-2017) of package quantregForest.   It's a very nice package.   In the documentation, function `varImpPlot.qrf()` is listed as a valid function.    However, when I try to use it, I get the following message:

> Error in varImpPlot.qrf(qrf) : could not find function
>   "varImpPlot.qrf"

I also tried `?varImpPlot.qrf` and `??varImpPlot.qrf`.   They don't provide any information.   Searching the web, I couldn't find any additional information.

Nicolai Meinshausen and Lukas Schiesser are listed as the authors of the package.   Does anyone know how to contact them to let them know there's problem?

Comment: There is a [varImpPlot](https://github.com/cran/quantregForest/blob/master/R/varImpPlot.R). You need to show us the code you're using. What makes you think `varImpPlot.qrf` exists?

Comment: you can go with the [github](https://github.com/lorismichel/quantregForest) or you take a look at the [one of meinhausens papers](https://stat.ethz.ch/~nicolai/quantregforests.pdf), there is an adress and e-mail listed. This paper was found through the github site. I don't want to post personal informations here. Also [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/~nicolai/) the stats profil of Meinhausen

Comment: @Roman  --  I got varImpPlot.qrf() from the quantregForest Vignette.     Here's a PDF [link](https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2016-04-11/web/packages/quantregForest/vignettes/quantregForest.pdf).   See pages 6-7.   I tried varImpPlot(), but it doesn't provide the capabilities of varImpPlot.qrf().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way to contact a package developer is through his [github account](https://github.com/lorismichel/quantregForest).

In this case the github account is not maintained by the author, so you can check other sources on the account. Take a look at [one of meinhausens papers](https://stat.ethz.ch/~nicolai/quantregforests.pdf), there is an adress and e-mail listed. This paper was found through the github site. I don't want to post personal informations here, but you can check the public links.

Also [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/~nicolai/) is the stats profile of Meinhausen with contact information (2019).

You could ask the maintainer of the package on Github or contact Meinhausen personally. Since it's about the package, i recommend github.

Comment: Thanks for the information.   Earlier, I tried the e-mail address in the paper and it bounced.    I just tried the above 2019 address and so far, it hasn't bounced.    If I get any additional information, I'll post it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is relevant to you anymore, but I stumbled across this question when asking pretty much the same question myself.

Looks like installing an historical version of the package, version 1.2, yields all the functionality shown in the vignette. To install the historical version use:

```
require(devtools)

install_version("quantregForest", version = "1.2", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Obviously this begs the question as to why some functionality is dropped between v1.2 and v1.3. All I've found to that end is the following:

https://github.com/lorismichel/quantregForest/issues/3